# Format mutiple inputs with mutiple categories for a functional keras model and feed it to the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can't figure out how to correctly feed training data to a functional keras model. I have two input types: Image data and float numbers, each number belonging to one image. This data is classified into 6 classes. How do I need to format my input data and how do I need to define it in my keras network? 
The image data is analyzed by a CNN and should then be concatenated with the float numbers. Afterwards, three dense layers are used for classification. There doesn't seem to be an example or tutorial that is similar to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate inputs:

```
imageInput = Input(image_shape) #often, image_shape is (pixelsX, pixelsY, channels)    
floatInput = Input(float_shape) #if one number per image, shape is: (1,)
```

The convolutional part:

```
convOut = SomeConvLayer(...)(imageInput)
convOut = SomeConvLayer(...)(convOut)
#...
convOut = SomeConvLayer(...)(convOut)
```

If necessary, do something similar with the other input.

Joining the two branches:

```
#Please make sure you use compatible shapes
#You should probably not have spatial dimensions anymore at this point
#Probably some kind of GloobalPooling:
convOut = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(convOut)

#concatenate the values:
joinedOut = Concatenate()([convOut,floatInput]) 
    #or some floatOut if there were previous layers in the float side
```

Do more stuff with your joined output:

```
joinedOut = SomeStuff(...)(joinedOut)
joinedOut = Dense(6, ...)(joinedOut)
```

Create the model with two inputs:

```
model = Model([imageInput,floatInput], joinedOut)
```

Train with:

```
model.fit([X_images, X_floats], classes, ...)
```

Where `classes` is a "one-hot encoded" tensor containing the correct class(es) for each image.

---

There isn't "one correct solution", though. You could try a lot of different things, such as "adding the number" somewhere in the middle of the convolutions, or multiplying it, or creating more convolutions after you manage to concatenate the values somehow.... this is art.

### The input data

The input and output data should be **numpy arrays**.

The arrays should be shaped as:

```
- Image input: `(number_of_images, side1, side2, channels)`    
- Floats input: `(number_of_images, number_of_floats_per_image)`    
- Outputs: `(number_of_images, number_of_classes)`
```

Keras will know everything necessary from these shapes, row 0 in all arrays will be image 0, row 1 will be image 1 and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I have most of this, but this is the part where I'm stuck:model.fit([X_images, X_floats], classes, ...).  How does keras know where the input data is, and how has the input to be structured (file format, certain folder structure?). Somehow I need to tell keras that it has to expect six classes and what images belong to what class. In addition to that, I need to tell him, what float value belongs to what image, no? In other words: How do X_images and X_floats need to be defined?

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps. If you happen to be in Germany, I'll get you a beer ;) Just one more question: If I understand it correctly, you don't tell Keras what input images/float belong to what classes, right? Why not? I have labled data, so shouldn't I provide him information about the image lables? Or is this stored in the "classes" parameter?

Comment: This is in the `classes` var in `fit`. It is the `Outputs` mentioned in the last section of the answer. /// I'm from Brazil :D --- If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: Ok, so if I have 1200 images (and 1200 floats of course), 200 for each class, then the input would be (1200, 256,256,3) and (1200,1). The Output, or "classes" would be (200,6)? --Yes, marked as solved! Thanks again.

Comment: The output would be `(1200,6)`. 6 classes per image.

Comment: This will be a "one-hot encoded" vector with 0's. Only the correct class will have the value 1 for each image.

Comment: Alright. I realized I misunderstood some things about how Keras works. Anyway, I managed to get my network working! Although my accuracy is only slightly higher than 1/6 haha. Is there a recommended network design for float numbers?

Comment: I'd initially try normalizing them between -1 and +1, but I'm not sure there is a specific network for "single floats".

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Please have a look at this [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423972/create-keras-input-array-numpy-append-does-not-work-correctly). I suspect it's just a small detail, but I can't figure it out.