# Create Keras input array, numpy.append does not work correctly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, append

I'm trying to create an input array for a functional Keras model. I have a set of images that I collect in a single np array, so the array has the shape: `(nr_images,img_width,img_height,nr_channels)`

I use this code:

```
files = glob.glob ("data/train/part2/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image=cv2.resize(image,(256,256))
    train.append (image)
train = np.array(train,dtype='float32')
np.save('train',train)
```

The resulting array dimension is `(426, 256, 256, 3)`. So it seems to work.

But if I look at the images stored in the array by:

```
image_train=np.load("train.npy")
image=image_train[0]       #Look at the first image
img = Image.fromarray(image,'RGB')
img.show()
```

I get rubbish:[image: Example]

My Keras results are super bad, so I suspect that it has something to do with the input.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The name of the saved array (`train256`) is different from the name of the loaded array (`train.npy`). Does this make a difference?

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility between `cv2` and `PIL`? What is the range of the arrays in each case? `train.max()` and `image_train.max()`.

Comment: @rvinas: No, just an editing error. The result is the same.

Comment: @DanielMöller: The maximum value of the created train.npy in the first bit of code and the loaded image_train are both 255. You are right, the compability seems to be the issue. If I use cv2.imwrite(image) instead of img.save(), I get my image in the correct form! Thanks a lot. So do you think that there might be a similar compability issue between cv2 and keras?

Comment: You'll be using "numpy", so no problem.